# Constructing sections of a cocartesian fibration

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Suppose $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{C}$ is a cocartesian fibration over (the nerve of) a classical category, and there is a section on zero simplices that sends $C$ to $s(C)$ such that, for every edge $f\colon C \to C'$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the Kan complex

$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{E}_{C'}}(f_!(s(C)), s(C'))$

is discrete (i.e. all higher $\pi_i$ vanish).

Is it true that data of an extension $s$ to a full section $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{E}$ is equivalent to data of morphisms

$t_f\colon [f_!](s(C)) \to s(C')$

in the homotopy category $h\mathcal{E}_{C'}$ such that, for every two composable morphisms $f\colon C \to C'$ and $g\colon C' \to C''$,

$t_g \circ [g_!](t_f) ~= t_{g\circ f}$

in the homotopy category $h\mathcal{E}_{C''}$ (under the canonical identification of $[g_!]\circ [f_!]$ with $[(g\circ f)_!]$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Consider the full subcategory $\mathcal S$ of $\mathcal E$ spanned by the objects $s(C)$.

It is clear that a section extending $s$ is the same thing as a section $\mathcal C\to \mathcal S$ extending $s$.

But I claim that $\mathcal S$ is a $1$-category: indeed the fiber of $\hom_\mathcal E(s(C),s(C'))\to \hom_\mathcal C(C,C')$ over $f$ is $\hom_{\mathcal E_C'}(f_!s(C),s(C'))$, and so is discrete, and the base $\hom_\mathcal C(C,C')$ is also discrete. Of course if $E\to B$ is a map to a discrete space where each fiber is discrete, $E$ must be discrete too (say by the long exact sequence of homotopy groups)

In particular, a section $\mathcal C\to \mathcal S$ extending $s$ is just an ordinary functor between ordinary categories : you have to pick images $s(f)$'s for every $f$ that compose well. Because $\mathcal S \subset \mathcal E$ and the latter is coCartesian over $\mathcal C$, you can reformulate the data of $s(f)$ in the way you did, and "compose well" accordingly.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks! I was missing the part that in order to get discreteness of the Hom spaces, it is enough to check discreteness on fibers. 

But just to make sure: to get that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{E}}(s(C), s(C'))$ is discrete, one needs to show that the map $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{E}}(s(C), s(C')) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(C, C')$ is a Kan fibration in the first place? But this is automatic since $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{C}$ is an inner fibration of $\infty$-categories.

Comment: Well if you were computing *strict* fibers, yes, you would need that; but I was computing homotopy fibers so I was implicitly replacing it with a Kan fibration. The actual strict fiber of this map, I have no clue what it is, and in fact it will depend on your model for $\hom_\mathcal E$